# why this php cURL function can't work

Tags: php

```
function get_data($url) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
```

i find this function from the internet. when i test it in a php file using this code `$returned_content = get_data('http://google.com');` but it can't work.and get a "301 Moved Permanently" The document has moved here.   error. why?

Comment: What happens or doesn't happen?

Comment: Are your getting a 302 Moved http error? or something similar. Elaborate man.

Comment: yeap,i get a 302 Moved http error.how to correct the code. thank you

Answer (score 34, accepted):

According to your comments, you are getting a 302 status code. Try

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
```

to follow 30x redirects.

Manual on [`curl_setopt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: @runeveryday because the remote server passes you a `302` header redirect and gives a `location:` string in the body. A normal browser will automatically follow to the new location (triggering a new request). With curl, you have to explicitly tell it to follow. See this page on status codes and what they mean: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.htmlhttp://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Answer (score 3):

add one more option to your get_data function :

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);`

Google is redirecting you to the local google servers and your curl call currently isn't chasing redirects.

oh yeah,
and do a `var_dump($returned_content);` to see the results :P

Answer (score -1):

Might be just as easy as adding an "echo"
Try following line :

```
echo get_data('http://google.com');
```

Also, please check if cURL module is activate in the PHP.ini

To find out easily just put following lines in a new file called info.php

```
<?php
 phpinfo();

?>
```

Search for cUrl.

If you can't find it please have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php to see what is involved to install the php curl module

OR add following to your curl options:

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,TRUE);

And sorry for the double posts.

Comment: If the cURL extension is not activated he would get an undefined function error in the first place... -_-

Comment: curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,TRUE); Should do

Comment: Because you receive a 302 status code. If you want to know more have a read through  http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php and http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html to get a better understanding of the status codes.